# Insertar etiqueta a un componente Vue.js dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un componente "hijo" vue.js con varias etiquetas que son propiedades boolean.

```
 <p-componente etiqueta1 etiqueta2></p-componente>
```

¿Podría añadir una tercera etiqueta dinámicamente?, o sea, mediante algúna forma en Javascript, añadir una etiqueta3 desde el componente padre.

```
 <p-componente etiqueta1 etiqueta2 etiqueta3></p-componente>
```

Realmente, no se si habría alguna manera de hacerlo en methods, mounted, created, etc.

Comment: No es lo recomendable, pudes utilizar la función `data` y asignar valores dinámicos que pueden ser utilizados por los hijos.